# How to set any flag in the where clause of a sql statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written the following SQL query inorder to retrieve values using the following condition. Now, if I want to set a flag at the end of any comparison how am I supposed to do it??

```
 select 
     x.transaction_id 
 from 
     nsbt_atm_trx_log_13763 x 
 inner join  
     nsbt_host_trx_log_13763 y on x.transaction_id = y.transaction_id
 where  
     to_char(x.transaction_date) <> to_char(y.transaction_date) 
     or to_char(x.business_date) <> to_char(y.business_date) 
     or to_char(x.transaction_value_date) <> to_char(y.transaction_value_date) 
     or x.transaction_type<> y.transaction_type 
     or x.account_number <> y.account_number 
     or x.customer_id <> y.customer_id 
     or x.transaction_amount <> y.transaction_amount;
```

Now at the end of every 'or' condition I need to set a flag. Like if the first condition is true then I would like to set flag to 1 else for the second condition I would like to set it to 2. and so on.

Comment: You cannot embed a `flag set` as you call it

Comment: but I tried using a case and an if statement as well but am not able to do it .

Comment: please tag the question with only the appropriate rdbms. is this sql going to work in mysql and sql server?

Comment: sorry for the wrong tags

Comment: `to_char(x.transaction_date) <> to_char(y.transaction_date) ` Firstly, why are you comparing **strings** instead of **dates**? Secondly, why are your relying on your locale-specific **NLS** settings? you must always specify the format model explicitly. You should just leave the date as it is for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "case when" condition in you output like this

```
select x.transaction_id 
case when to_char(x.transaction_date)<>to_char(y.transaction_date) then 1 else
case when to_char(x.business_date)<>to_char(y.business_date) then 2 else
case when to_char(x.transaction_value_date) <> to_char(y.transaction_value_date) then 3 else
case when  x.transaction_type<> y.transaction_type then 4 else
case when  x.customer_id <> y.customer_id then 5 else 6 end end end end end
as columnname
from nsbt_atm_trx_log_13763 x inner join  nsbt_host_trx_log_13763 y on x.transaction_id = y.transaction_id
 where  to_char(x.transaction_date)<>to_char(y.transaction_date) or
 to_char(x.business_date)<>to_char(y.business_date) or
 to_char(x.transaction_value_date) <> to_char(y.transaction_value_date) or
 x.transaction_type<> y.transaction_type or
 x.account_number <> y.account_number or
 x.customer_id <> y.customer_id or
 x.transaction_amount <> y.transaction_amount;
```